# In java, is execution within a try block continued if an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, exception

```
try {
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()
}
catch(Exception e) {}
```

if `doSomething()` throws an exception, will `doSomethingElse()` be executed? If not, is there a way to make it be executed (but if `doSomethingElse` throws the same exception, still catching it)?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 5):

No, control jumps to the catch clause.

This is something you could easily have tested for yourself...

```
public void doSomethingThatThrowsAnException() throws Exception {
   throw new Exception();
}

try {
    System.out.println("Before");
    doSomethingThatThrowsAnException();
    System.out.println("After");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Caught");
}
```

Prints...

```
Before
Caught
```

Answer (score 0):

`doSomethingElse()` will not be executed if an exception is thrown in `doSomething()`. If an exception is thrown in the `try` block, the `catch` block is executed next. The `finally` block will always execute whether or not an exception was raised and is typically used to clean up resources.